# Internacionalização Android - Desenvolvendo em Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, internacionalização, tradução

Como devo aplicar internacionalização para um app Android,usando línguas variadas?

Necessito que desenvolver um aplicativo Android onde as palavras originais em português devem ser traduzidas para as seguintes línguas : Alemão,Árabe(Arábia Saudita),Chinês,Grego e Italiano!

Já tenho dentro da minha pasta values um arquivo: strings.xml.. e criei as pasta para as línguas(onde estão as strings correspondentes), porém quando eu emulo o aplicativos nas línguas estrangeiras as palavras continuam em Português!

Minhas strings de cada um dos país já apresentam as palavras traduzidas,tanto que os arquivos quando abram tem o ícone da bandeira dos países!

Abaixo está a imagem de como estão nomeadas as pastas

[image: Pastas]

```html
<string name="app_name">Esercizio di internazionalizzazione</string>
<string name="país">Italia</string>
<string name="comida">Pizza</string>
<string name="food">Pizza</string>
<string name="bandeira">Bandiera dell\'Italia</string>



 <string name="app_name">Exercício Internacionalização</string>
    <string name="país">Brasil</string>
    <string name="comida">Feijoada</string>
    <string name="bandeira">Bandeira do Brasil</string>
    <string name="food">Feijoada</string>
```

Existe uma maneira correta de nomear as pastas? Estou fazendo algum passo errado?

Comment: Você traduziu e incluiu as strings nas respectivas pastas?

Comment: ramaral - eu abri minha string onde estão as palavras em portugues,depois abir o editor de linguagem..adicionei as lingua e fiz as traduçoes..foram criadas pastas de acordo com o que vc disse ,mas ainda sim não traduz

Comment: Não vejo nada de errado.

Comment: ramaral teria como falar com vc pelo "chat" do stack? assim posso te mostrar os códigos,pois não consigo ver onde está errado

Comment: Tudo indica que sim, no entanto verifique se as strings foram criadas nos respectivos arquivos Strings. Como você está fazendo no emulador?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os recursos da aplicação são carregados na inicialização do aplicativo e criação dos componentes, de acordo com as configurações definidas no sistema. Para testar seu app em chinês, uma das alternativas mais simples é definir o idioma do sistema para chinês e abrir o app novamente.

Você também pode alterar as configurações de idioma do aplicativo de maneira programática (em runtime) conforme explica a postagem [How to change the language on Android at runtime and don’t go mad](https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758), que inclui trechos de código para diferentes níveis de API.

As pastas devem ser nomeadas de acordo com o padrão [BCP 47](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47). Experimente usar `values-ar`, `values-de`, `values-el`, `values-it` e `values-zh`.

Comment: Mathias - Ao criar as pastas,traduzindo as palavras pra língua correspondente,as strings ja serão criadas automaticamente nessas pastas?

Comment: As pastas estão bem nomeadas, Quando se pretende indicar uma variante regional ela deve ser indica com `-rREGIÃO`.

Comment: @CarolM supostamente o editor deve sim armazenar um arquivo XML com as strings dentro da pasta correta. Em termos de estrutura, todos os arquivos serão iguais, mudando apenas os valores (textos). Você pode conferir abrindo o arquivo `strings.xml` de cada pasta e verificando se confere com o que você escreveu no editor visual.

Comment: @ramaral segundo o validador disponível em http://schneegans.de/lv/, alguns nomes não são válidos. De qualquer maneira, renomear as pastas de modo a tornar a localização mais abrangente pode ser uma boa maneira de testar e limitar as causas do problema.

Answer (score 0):

Demorei pra vir fechar a pergunta ,desculpem!
Consegui descobir o erro,eu não tinha colocado @string no Id e no Description!

Comment: Você tentou postar um comentário e acabou postando uma resposta, porque deve ter usado sem perceber a caixa de texto para respostas. Procure usar para comentários a opção de comentar, é mais apropriada para isso.